# What is the role of the jquery object in this case?

Tags: jquery, trim

My understanding of the jquery object isn't clear. The Jquery/javascript code below has a jQuery object on the 4th line where trim is called. Is the trim function a method of the jQuery object which returns the results within the parentheses?  I simply need this confirmed or clarified.

```
$('.tabs > ul li a').on('mouseover', function(){
var that = $(this),
    tabs= that.parent().parent().parent(),
    target=jQuery.trim(that.attr('href').substring(1)),
    items=tabs.find('ul li');

    items.removeClass('selected').find('a[href="#' + target +'"]').parent().addClass('selected');

    tabs.find('.tab').show();
    tabs.find('.tab:not(".'+target+'")').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Trim function removes the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string) not parentheses : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/

Comment: `jQuery.trim` and `$.trim` are the same thing in this case; in both cases it's a function of the `jQuery` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions defined within `jQuery` can be categorised into:

1. Global functions, i.e. `jQuery.trim()`, `jQuery.inArray()`, also known as the [utility functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) which reside in the `jQuery` namespace.
2. Set functions, i.e. `.each()`, that operate on a set of elements and reside in the `jQuery.fn` prototype.

It's important to understand that `jQuery` is both a constructor *and* a namespace onto which functions can be attached.

To illustrate the difference:

```
// iterate over an array or object
$.each(arr, function(value) {
});
```

Versus:

```
// iterate over a set of elements based on a given selector
$('div').each(function() {
});
```

To answer your question; `trim()` is a function inside the `jQuery` namespace (which is an object, but it's not *the* jQuery object that's used e.g. when you manipulate DOM elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can see how [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) function works in [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/39b76064d9400295a383291ab6e821e259b67832/src/core.js#L327-L331)

```
trim: function( text ) {
    return text == null ?
    "" :
    ( text + "" ).replace( rtrim, "" );
},
```

To make it more clear, note [what rtrim means](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/39b76064d9400295a383291ab6e821e259b67832/src/core.js#L28)

```
rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,
```

See [explanation of that regex in URL](http://regex101.com/r/aM4vL6/1).

It just converts your text to string and then, removes whitespaces, BOM's, NBSP's and other stuff from start and end of it.

[Few lines above](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/39b76064d9400295a383291ab6e821e259b67832/src/core.js#L20) `rtrim` you will see, what is the role of `jQuery` object citing [docs](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/39b76064d9400295a383291ab6e821e259b67832/src/core.js#L21)

> The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'

It is simply an object, that carries jquery realted attributes, one of them is `trim` which is of type `function` and value of it I already described above.

Comment: -1. OP is not asking what `$.trim()` does; rather to confirm whether his understanding of what `jQuery.trim` is is correct or not.

Comment: @Jack By seeing source code of function, you can clearly see what jQuery.trim is and what it isn't

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't explain the role `jQuery` plays, which is the title of his question ...

Comment: The role you have described is that of what `new jQuery.fn.init()` returns and that has no `trim()` function defined on it.